# Azure data factory name output folder as the current timestamp

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am running a copy activity and I am trying to place the output file in a folder that is named after the current the timestamp. I am using utcnow('G') so I get the 10/21/2020 1:30:45PM. But when I run it it puts the file within 3 nested folders like this 10 / 21 / 2020 1:30:45PM/ file. It splits the date to make the month its own folder, the day its own folder within that, and the year and time its own folder within that. I am completely dumbfounded on why this is happening. Obviously I just want a single folder. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `utcnow('G')` contains '/'. When you have '/' in your folder path, this means you have sub folder. So you will create three folders:10,21 and 2020 1:30:45PM. If you only want a single folder, you can replace '/' to other character like '-'. Or  just use other date format which not contains '/',such as 'utcnow('o')'.More detail,you can refer to `utcnow()` function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#utcnow.